# Select text with mouseup event and dbclick event with call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

I look for jquery select text event and I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/43c8h/16/).
in this example mouseup event work as well as dbclick event.

i add a function to this code with return value but now dbclick doesn't work.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/WBLQz/3/)

> if (!window.James) {
>           James = {};
>       }

```
James.Selector = {};

James.Selector.mouseup = function (e) {
    var userSelection;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        userSelection = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        // should come last; Opera!
        userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    var selectedText = userSelection;
    if (userSelection.text) selectedText = userSelection.text;

    if (selectedText != '') {
        return selectedText + '------' + e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function (e) {
        alert(James.Selector.mouseup(e))
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    });
});
```

Comment: it is alerting, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: i just want get returned value...

Comment: "e" is the returned value!

Comment: ok, but why dbclick doesn't work?

Comment: I agree with Amin. You are currently using bind("mouseup", ..), so your function appears to be doing what it is suppose to. What do you want to do with it? have you tried console.log to see what is in the object?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato no, unfortunately i don't have enough skill

Comment: @AminJafari aghaye jafari khaheshan javab bede... nemidunam tunestam manzuramo begam ya na...

Comment: vaghean na, aslan motevajehe manzuret nemisham, yekam bishtar tozih bede lotfan

Comment: bebin tuye oun jsfiddle avali vaghti ye matn ro che tu halate aadi che be double click entekhab koni dorost alert mide

Comment: vali tuye 2vomi k man ye function behesh ezafe kardam dbclick k koni kar nemikone...

Comment: javabamo bebin fek konam fahmidam chi mikhay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/WBLQz/11/

just set a `setTimeout()` to let it be able for dblclick as well.

Comment: I just figured that out, wait I'll update my answer in a minute!

Comment: dobare javabo emtehan kon!

Comment: is that what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

the statement causing the problem is this: Lets call it "problem statement":  `if (selectedText != '') {`

in the original code, the program outputs the alert once this condition is met. So stepping through both code...

You single click:

- the original code reaches problem statement and does NOT output the alert as nothing is selected
- Your code reaches problem statement and does NOT return a value as the problem statement fails, however your      alert statement ALWAYS executed.

So in original code it may seem as the function is called on doubleclick but not single click. This is not true, it is always executed. but with browsers these days, 'double clicking' highlights a string between white spaces, or a char, thus `(selectedText != '')`

You can fix this with a simple if statement before the alert is executed

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function (e) {
        if (James.Selector.mouseup(e) !== undefined)
        alert(James.Selector.mouseup(e))            
    });
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
});
```

Where `if (James.Selector.mouseup(e) !== undefined)` will the only execute the alert if something selected, or double clicked.

Please note that I moved the statement:  `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();`
outside of the bound function, so the selection is not erased after you close the alert.